# Dialog com dataTable não é exibido

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tenho um dialog com um `dataTable`, porém, ao clicar no botão que deveria abrí-lo, isso não acontece.

Ele também possui um `dataTable` dentro dele que deveria ter valores respectivos a linha na qual ele corresponde no `dataTable`.
Poderia me dizer por que isso ocorre?

```
<p:commandButton value="Buscar" action="#{ocorrenciaViewMB.obterOcorrencia}" ajax="true" update=":form"></p:commandButton>
    <p:dataTable var="ocorrencia" value="#{ocorrenciaViewMB.listaocorrencia}" emptyMessage="Nenhuma ocorrência de risco encontrada." widgetVar="riscoTabela" sortMode="multiple" draggableColumns="true"
     draggableRows="true" resizableColumns="true" caseSensitiveSort="false">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:outputPanel>     
                <h:outputText value="#{msgs.OcorrenciasDeRisco}" />            
            </p:outputPanel>
        </f:facet>
        <p:column headerText="#{msgs.Codigo}" colspan="1"
                 sortBy="#{ocorrencia.codigo}">
            <h:outputText value="#{ocorrencia.codigo}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column style="width:32px;text-align: center">
            <p:commandButton  value="Modal" type="button"  oncick="PF('modal').show();" />
        </p:column>
        <p:dialog header="Danos" closeOnEscape="true" showEffect="fade" position="center" hideEffect="explode" widgetVar="modal"  id="modal" modal="true" height="50">
            <p:dataTable var="dano"  id="dataTableDano" value="#{ocorrencia.listaDeDanos}" emptyMessage="Nenhum encontrado." sortMode="multiple" draggableColumns="true" draggableRows="true" resizableColumns="true" caseSensitiveSort="false">
                <h:outputText value="Código" />
                <h:outputText value="#{dano.codigo}" />
                <h:outputText value="Descrição" />
                <h:outputText value="#{dano.descricao}" />
            </p:dataTable>
        </p:dialog> 
    </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Corrija a escrita do `onclick` no botão que irá atualizar o dialog para `onclick`. Feito isso, defina um ajax false no seu botão. Também está faltando uma chamada que dê um update no seu dialog, já que deverá pegar valores dinâmicos de acordo com a linha selecionada na tabela.

Answer (score 0):

Passe o `<p:Dialog` para fora do `</p:dataTable>` depois mude o onClick para `oncomplete="PF('modal').show()"`

seu código ficará assim.
Faça o teste e veja se funciona dessa forma.

```
    <p:commandButton value="Buscar" action="#{ocorrenciaViewMB.obterOcorrencia}" ajax="true" update=":form"></p:commandButton>
        <p:dataTable var="ocorrencia" value="#{ocorrenciaViewMB.listaocorrencia}" emptyMessage="Nenhuma ocorrência de risco encontrada." widgetVar="riscoTabela" sortMode="multiple" draggableColumns="true"
         draggableRows="true" resizableColumns="true" caseSensitiveSort="false">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:outputPanel>     
                    <h:outputText value="#{msgs.OcorrenciasDeRisco}" />            
                </p:outputPanel>
            </f:facet>
            <p:column headerText="#{msgs.Codigo}" colspan="1"
                     sortBy="#{ocorrencia.codigo}">
                <h:outputText value="#{ocorrencia.codigo}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column style="width:32px;text-align: center">
                <p:commandButton  value="Modal" type="button"  oncomplete="PF('modal').show();" />
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>

<p:dialog header="Danos" closeOnEscape="true" showEffect="fade" position="center" hideEffect="explode" widgetVar="modal"  id="modal" modal="true" height="50">
                <p:dataTable var="dano"  id="dataTableDano" value="#{ocorrencia.listaDeDanos}" emptyMessage="Nenhum encontrado." sortMode="multiple" draggableColumns="true" draggableRows="true" resizableColumns="true" caseSensitiveSort="false">
                    <h:outputText value="Código" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{dano.codigo}" />
                    <h:outputText value="Descrição" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{dano.descricao}" />
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:dialog>
```

Faça um teste colocando modal="false" e veja se funciona também.